# i tried to create WordPress custom_menu in admin panel. but it give the callback_function error

Tags: wordpress, admin, panel

I tried to create a WordPress custom_menu in the admin panel, but it gives a callback_function error.

```php
add_action('admin_menu', 'custom_menu');
function custom_menu() { 

  add_menu_page( 
      'Page Title', 
      'File Upload', 
      'edit_posts', 
      'menu_slug', 
      'page_callback_function', 
      'dashicons-media-spreadsheet' 

     );
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxkJ6.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Images of code or error messages are not helpful, please update your question to include all the information we need so that we can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'wpse_183245_upload_dir' );

    function wpse_183245_upload_dir( $dirs ) {
        $dirs['subdir'] = '/up';
        $dirs['path'] = $dirs['basedir'] . '/up';
        $dirs['url'] = $dirs['baseurl'] . '/up';
        return $dirs;
    }



$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir(); 
$user_dirname = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . 'up';
if(!file_exists($user_dirname)) wp_mkdir_p($user_dirname);
$upload = wp_upload_dir();
$upload_dir = $upload['basedir'] . $directory_path;
$permissions = 0755;
$oldmask = umask(0);
if (!is_dir($upload_dir)) mkdir($upload_dir, $permissions);
$umask = umask($oldmask);
$chmod = chmod($upload_dir, $permissions);

add_action('admin_menu', 'custom_menu');
function custom_menu() { 

  add_menu_page( 
      'Page Title', 
      'File Upload', 
      'upload_files', 
      'menu_slug', 
      'my_admin_page_contents', 
      'dashicons-media-spreadsheet' 

     );
}

function ada(){
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir(); 
$user_dirname = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . 'up';


}
function my_admin_page_contents() {
    ?>
        <h1>
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#" method="POST">
Please choose a file: <input name="file" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit" />
</form> 
        </h1>
    <?php
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );

//add_filter( 'upload_dir');


$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file'];
$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
$movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );


if ( $movefile ) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
 
  
    //var_dump( $movefile);
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}
}

require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );

echo list_files( $folder = '', $levels = 100, $exclusions = array() );

    ?>
```